# How to extend Locals interface in SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

The Svelte documentation shows how to set an element on locals in hooks: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks

```js
event.locals.user = await getUserInformation(event.cookies.get('sessionid'));
```

If I try to extend the locals Object in TypeScript I get an error, of not existing property.

> Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Locals'

The `App.Locals` interface is empty so it should be a normal error message of the system. How could I extend the `App.Locals` interface of Svelte with attributes like user or session and have this information also available in my server routes? I want to avoid to cast or define it everywhere by my self.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There should already be a `app.d.ts` which declares the interface in a new SvelteKit project. If you do not have such a file, you can just create your own declarations.

The interface is namespaced (see [`App`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#app)):

```js
declare namespace App {
    interface Locals {
        user: UserInfo; // Your type here
    }

    interface PageData {}

    interface Platform {}
}
```